# Which style sheet options should be set to export to a color PDF?

Tags: output-formatting, formatting

I have a Mathematica 10.4 notebook that I need to export to a color PDF.  In looking through the other postings, I have tried setting the PrintingStyleEnvironment to Printout but cannot seem to export to a color PDF.

```
SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], PrintingStyleEnvironment->"Printout", ShowSyntaxStyles->True];
```

Is there a list of option settings that should be made to obtain a color PDF?

Comment: related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27171/5478

Comment: I think it's a duplicate, but I didn't vote. Please verify. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/451/12

Comment: so Doug, any feedback?